# LDAP Calls from web service is cauisng connection reset

Tags: java, rest, ldap, jndi, connection-pooling

I have developed REST web services that connect to LDAP and perform LDAP operations. This service is deployed on weblogic server. Connectivity to LDAP is being initialized when the application is deployed.

```
public class Initializer implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    // Set up environment for creating initial context
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,Constants.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,Constants.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,password);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,LDAP_URL);

    // Create initial context
    ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

    }

 public static LdapContext getLDAPContext() {
    return ctx;
    }

}
```

So I use `getLDAPContext()` to get LDAP connection and call JNDI operations to perform LDAP operations. This works fine for LDAP on single node.

In higher environments, we have LDAP deployed on 2 nodes(different machines) with replication enabled on both nodes. We have VIP configured on these 2 nodes.

Now, when I provide LDAP VIP URL and take LDAP connection, I am seeing connection resets exceptions in my web service calls after some time. I believe this is causing due to VIP URL I am using. I am not seeing this behavior if I point to single node LDAP server.

I tried to set no timeout like this. But it didnt help.

```
env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "-1");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If your VIP load balance the request it is a normal behaviour as LDAP is a protocol which is stateful, so the connection opened through the VIP is opened only on ONE directory, not the two at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Most load balancers close the idle connections after a certain configured time interval. As I see you are creating the connection during init and use this connection throughout rest of the calls to LDAP. Once load balancer has closed the connection and at client side (in your LDAP calls) you try to use that connection that is why you are getting those exceptions as that LDAP connection handle has gone stale. You need to catch the exception and depending on type of exception you need to do init on connection again.